# Laravel,blade, vue.js and @if (@{{ }})

Tags: php, laravel, if-statement, laravel-blade, vue.js

I am having a problem with variables devielve vue.js me ... I explain better

```
        <tr

        @if(@{{users.id}} != 1) // this is the error

        Class="danger"
        @else
        class="success"
        @endif
        >
```

I can not define a @if (@ {{user.id in laravel

before defined

```
@foreach($datos as $dato)
<tbody id={{$dato->id}}>
<tr                                 
@if($dato->id !=1)
class="danger"
@else
Class="success"
@endif >
```

and it worked but I had to put a select box, and Use varaible vue.js to collect and return the data I...

excuse my English is not my mother tongue and hinders me

Comment: What's the exact error message? Please update post.

Comment: syntax error, unexpected '{' ...
so that the variable defined within if

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I do not believe you can use vuejs code (such as your `@{{users.id}}`) inside a laravel `@if()` because everything inside the `@if()` is being treated as PHP code. If it makes sense in your particular application, make use of vuejs's `v-if` implementation, such as `<div v-if="users.id !== 1"> INSERT WHATEVER HERE </div>`

Comment: I had that this was the solution ... thank you very much for answering